# Getting keys of an object that has same values

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, javascript-objects

I have an object like:

```
 Object {v: 1, b: 1, n: 1, m: 1, c: 2, d: 3}
```

I am trying to collect keys that has same values and generate an array (so in this case `[v, b, n, m]`.

So if I know `1`, how can I get `v,b,n,m` in an array?

Comment: Any attempts? Loop over object, compare value with 1, if `true`, add the key to an array.

Comment: Actually, I wanted to know if there was anything else quicker than for loop. Maybe a method or something

Comment: @senty Okay, still you need to show attempts. Add the code in question.

Comment: So is the duplicated value known for you in advance i.e. you need a function like `getKeysWithDuplicatedValues({v: 1, b: 1, n: 1, m: 1, c: 2, d: 3}, 1)` that should return `['v', 'b' , 'n', 'm']` or you need a function that detects all repeated items i.e. `getKeysWithDuplicatedValues({v: 1, b: 1, n: 1, m: 1, c: 2, d: 2}` that should return `{'1': ['v', 'b' , 'n', 'm'], '2': ['c', 'd']}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)** to get key values of the object, then filter values based on your condition using **[`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)**

```js
var obj = {
    v: 1,
    b: 1,
    n: 1,
    m: 1,
    c: 2,
    d: 3
  },
  val = 1;

var res = Object.keys(obj).filter(function(v) {
  return obj[v] == val;
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(res, null, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: `Object.keys` only returns properties owned by the object. That check is redundant.

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean with hasOwnProperty. Just for learning, can you please show it in an example? Would be very helpful for me and others on that topic..

Comment: @senty—it's not required, per Oka's comment, so `Object.keys(obj).filter(function(v){return obj[v]==val;})`.

Answer (score 1):

Performance? Simple [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop.

```js
var myObj = {v: 1, b: 1, n: 1, m: 1, c: 2, d: 3};

function collect (obj, value) {
  var arr = [];
  
  for (var key in obj)
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key) && obj[key] === value)
      arr.push(key);
  
  return arr;
}

console.log(collect(myObj, 1));
```

Fancy? [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), and [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```js
var myObj = {v: 1, b: 1, n: 1, m: 1, c: 2, d: 3};

function collect (obj, value) {
  return Object.keys(obj).filter(key => obj[key] === value);
}

console.log(collect(myObj, 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

using the [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) library you can do the following

```
var object = {v: 1, b: 1, n: 1, m: 1, c: 2, d: 3};

var output = _.map(object, function(value, key){
    if(value == 1){
        return key
    }
}).filter(function(value){
    return value; 
});

console.log(output);
```

Comment: That's more code than plain JS, what is there to recommend it?

Comment: @RobG if you use es6 and the ternary operator it's close to the same: var output = _.map(object, (val, key) => val == 1 ? key : false).filter((val) => val );

Comment: but yes, in this instance it is better just to use plain js. There are a lot of utilities in underscore so I tend to have it in most projects, and being able to use map on objects as well as arrays in my opinion makes it better than the plain js map.